# B Cell Differentiation

Tags: differentiation

During the differentiation of B cells in bone marrow, **recombination** occurs in light chain and heavy chain genes to produce a single type of functional gene which determines the type of light chain and the heavy chain produced by that B cell. 
Therefore, a single B cell and its generation displays a single type of antigen receptor on its cell surface.

My question is-
Recombination will occur in both the copies of the light chain gene present on the homologous chromosomes (same with the heavy chain gene).

So, **the combination produced on the homologous chromosomes should be different. 
Is it really so?  And if not, then how come they are identical?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mechanism in T and B cells called allelic exclusion. This means that most of the times only a single allele is used by building the light chain and the other is excluded. Incomplete allelic exclusion may contribute to auto-immune diseases, because cells using two different light chains can potentially recognize both pathogens and healthy human cells<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunoglobulin_light_chain#Structure),[2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3008371/),[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allelic_exclusion),[4](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1782513/),[5](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2928156/),[6](http://www.jimmunol.org/content/jimmunol/170/1/182.full.pdf),[7](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3594800/),[8](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20727027)</sup>.